# Express doesn't set-cookie when SameSite is none

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, session, passport.js

I have read a lot of other similar questions, but I couldn't solve the issue.

My setup is Node + Express + PassportJs and everything works in development, but I have problems on production.

With the following code, I see that the session cookie is sent back in the response, but I also get a message saying that it won't be applied as `SameSite` is lax (the default) and the response comes from another site (frontend and backend do not have the same origin).

```
app.use( 
    session({ 
        secret: "foo", 
        resave: false, 
        saveUninitialized: false, 
        store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_DB_CONN_STRING! }), 
        cookie: { httpOnly: true }
    }) 
);
```

[image]

So I changed it to this, so to specify `SameSite` and `Secure` in production, but at this point, **no cookie is set anymore!**

```
app.use( 
    session({ 
        secret: "foo", 
        resave: false, 
        saveUninitialized: false, 
        store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_DB_CONN_STRING! }), 
        cookie: isProduction ? { httpOnly: true, sameSite: "none", secure: true } : {}  // <-- only change
    }) 
);
```

[image]

What could be the cause? I've tried to fix it by playing with CORS (no success) and other 100 things. Yet it seems some quirk I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

depending on what service you use to deploy your API(netlify, render.com, heroku other...) you have to enable proxy

```
 this.app.enable('trust proxy');
```

it fixed my issue